# Fast and pythonic way to find out if an anagram is a palindrome?

Tags: python

Given a string, how do we check if any anagram of it can be a palindrome?

For example let us consider the string "AAC". An anagram of it is "ACA" which is a palindrome. We have to write a method which takes a string and outputs true if we can form a palindrome from any anagram of the given string. Otherwise outputs false.

This is my current solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def check(s):
    newdict = defaultdict(int)
    for e in s:
        newdict[e] += 1
    times = 0
    for e in newdict.values():
        if times == 2:
            return False
        if e == 1:
            times += 1
    return True
```

Any shorter solutions using the python library?

Comment: As you might have expected, no

Comment: Your algorithm thinks that "AAABBB" has an anagram which is a palindrome. This is incorrect.

Comment: Also returns true for 'AADC' that is incorrect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is shorter solution that uses the standard library, with a corrected algorithm (all the character counts must be even, except for at most one):

```
from collections import Counter
def check(s):
    return sum(1 for count in Counter(s).itervalues() if count % 2 == 1) <= 1
```

This is short but "slow", as the program goes through all the odd counts instead of stopping as soon as two are found. A faster solution that stops as soon as possible, is:

```
def check(s):
    odd_counts = (count for count in Counter(s).itervalues() if count % 2 == 1)
    try:
        next(odd_counts)  # Fails if there is no odd count
        next(odd_counts)  # Fails if there is one odd count
    except StopIteration:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out my mistake above and for providing this solution!

Comment: Instead of `sum(1 for count in ... if count %2 == 1)`, you can do `sum(count % 2 == 1 for count in ...)`, or even `sum(count % 2 for count in ...)`.

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion. However, the `if` form performs fewer sums, so I prefer it: no need to do more work than necessary. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably better fit for code golfing, but eh it is quite trivial.

Observe that palindromes require a balanced set of sides, so you need generally even number of inputs per type.  However a single odd item can be provided in the middle, so you can essentially raise that to a maximum of one set of characters that are odd.  This can be done with a single list comprehension

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def is_palindrome(letters):
...     return len([v for v in Counter(letters).values() if v % 2]) <= 1
... 
>>> is_palindrome('level')
True
>>> is_palindrome('levels')
False
>>> is_palindrome('levelss')
True
```

Oh wait, someone else beat with a solution, but that's what I got.

Comment: Yeah, same idea. Just to nitpick: you don't need to create a list in order to get the length of a finite iterator, though: `len(<iterator>)` works. This saves memory, in general (here, this is normally negligible).

Comment: Yeah, I know, could have just hit ( and ) twice but I did this in an interpreter and was going to post individual results per step.  No such nice rendering of internal contents for iterators, looking at `[1, 1]` vs `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7ff1b64d1730>
`

Comment: @EOL generator expressions *do not* have a length - eg, `len(a for a in range(10) if a%2)` is a TypeError.

Comment: @lvc You're right, my bad. I fixed my answer. I was a bit surprised myself, compared to what I seemed to remember. However, in principle, the length of an iterator could be defined (resulting in an infinite calculation time for infinite iterators): `sum(1 for _ in iterator)`—which is much more memory efficient than `len([…])`.

Answer (score 0):

Without using Counter:

```
>>> def isit(s):
...     ls = [ x % 2 for x in [s.count(x) for x in set(s)]]
...     return [False, True][all(ls) or ls.count(1) == 1]
...
>>> isit('abc')
False
>>> isit('abb')
True
>>> isit('abbd')
False
>>> isit('abbdd')
True
>>> isit('abbdda')
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not algorithmically the best, (if your strings are not extremely long it's not a problem), I'd like to provide a more readable solution.

```
from itertools import permutations

def has_palindrome(s):
    return any(c == c[::-1] for c in permutations(s,len(s)))
```